# How can I name a prediction

Tags: r

I would like to name a column when I have already created a forecast, how do I do this?

```
  previsao_tissue_historico <- stats::predict(modelo_tissue)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a column to the data frame you used in the model? If the data frame is `mydata`, then `mydata$previsao_tissue_historico <- stats::predict(modelo_tissue)`.